# Domain name does not work

Tags: domain-name-system, azure, domain, cname-record, .net

I created an app with azure, a such link https://viva.azurewebsites.net I got in the end.
After that I bought a domain name. The domain provider created a A-Record and CNAME-record, everything is well done. A couple of hours later I saw that the webisite does not work. It only shows the start page. When I log in the brower shows a blank page the following message: https://viva.azurewebsites.net refused to connect.
Does anyone know the problem may be?

Comment: All I see is a 404 page. You need to upload some content.

Comment: An online troubleshooting tool such as https://dnsviz.net/d/viva.azurewebsites.net/YQnTig/dnssec/ shows some errors and warnings in your DNS configuration that may have consequences for people browsing your website, or not, but you will need to sort that out with your DNS provider.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.